# Django tests with postgres - reset sequences

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing

So far development and tests have been done on SQLite, while production was on Postgres. Now everything needs to run on Postgres, and a large number of tests broke. The reason is, IDs for each test don't start with 1, but continue between tests.

One way how to fix this is to use [`TransactionTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/#advanced-features-of-transactiontestcase), so changing

```
class FooCase(APITestCase):
```

with

```
class FooCase(APITransactionTestCase):
    reset_sequences = True
```

This works, but it becomes slow

While I can try and fix tests, it is quite difficult because many tests have mocked methods. Is there another way, where I can reset sequences and keep it all fast and tidy?

Comment: Why specifically do your tests depend on sequences starting from 1?

Comment: Good thing you made the switch! Your app shouldn't be relied to sequences not having gaps!

Comment: @DanielRoseman When I create test users, I know their pk. I use that pk inside JSON `@mock.patch` uses (JSON being in another file for readability).

Answer (score 1):

You can reset sequences before tests using sql:

```
SELECT setval(sequence_name, 1), sequence_name FROM information_schema.sequences;
```

But remember the following:

```
SELECT currval('my_sequence'); --Returns 1
SELECT nextval('my_sequence'); --Returns 2
```

So, if you call `nextval` directly on your code, the sequence will return 2, instead of 1.

Also, sequences in postgres are like tables.

```
SELECT last_value FROM my_sequence; --Returns 1
```

But this approach bypass `currval` ACID protections, meaning that isn't concurrency safe.

Comment: But this doesn't exactly look like a _clean_ solution. In best case I would have to create a mixin and add to all tests. But it could work

Comment: you can add this code to the method that creates your test users

Comment: You're right, it's not a clean solution. But I guess the "problem" is the need to know the user id on unit testing. It isn't possible to discover this id before tests?

Comment: @michel.milezzi I know ID before the test (I get it on `setUp`), but I would need to somehow pass it to mocked response, and that becomes the problem, it all starts becoming overcomplicated.