# How can I reset a Django test database id's after each test?

Tags: python, django, database, shell, docker

I have a django app and I am running some unit tests on it. So the problem I am having is not when one test inserts into the test db. It is the tests that come after. Since each test is not saving the transaction, the entry from a previous test is not there **which is fine**, although the auto increment id's are increasing as if there are still entries into the database. Which I need to fix because I am inserting more data where I cannot control the id's given to it and need to be able to grab this specific data for the test. If I hard code the code to grab the objects I will have to change the code for every time I add a new test, which is not ideal.

I have multiple tests running, but for simplicity sake, I will show two.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import Model

class VersionMerge(TestCase):
   fixtures = ['initial_test_data.json']

   def test_model_test1(self):
       *Insert new data*
       *grab new data in*
       *Check data*

   def test_model_test2(self):
       *Insert new data*
       *grab new data*
       *Check data*
```

The problem arises in *test_model_test2* where when I try to grab the new data, I have to print the object out to see the id's to be able to grab it.

I have a solution on how I can fix this on the actual database but not the test one. For mine I need to be able to connect to a docker container and run a psql command to reset the table_id_seq.

```
docker exec -t  $CONTAINER_ID psql --dbname=test_database_name -username=user -c "SELECT setval('modelName_appName_id_seq', 2, true)"
```

This will go to the table and set the last id value used to be 2 to make the next id 3. However whenever I try to run the command from inside python using

```
cmd = "command above"
os.system(cmd)
```

and when I run this I get the following error.

```
sh: 1: docker: not found
sh: 1: docker: not found
```

Looking for any help on this, either a new solution to the problem or improvements on mine.

TLDR; I need to be able to modify data in the database that the django unit tests create.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.reset_sequences ?

Comment: @Ryan w Could you manage to find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue :) thanks

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43893144

Answer (score 8):

I got this to work by replacing `TestCase` with **TransactionTestCase** and set `reset_sequences=True`. However the tests are running slower.

```
from django.test import TransactionTestCase

class ViewTest(TransactionTestCase):
    reset_sequences = True

    def test_view_redirects(self):
       ...
```

Here's the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/advanced/#advanced-features-of-transactiontestcase)

Answer (score 6):

If you need a test to reset the primary key sequence, you can issue a RawSQL query doing that. How to do that exactly is answered in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4678411/219519).

An easier option is available if you're using pytest. We're using pytest and pytest-django in all our Django projects and it makes testing a breeze. pytest-django provdes [a database fixture that can take a boolean parameter to reset the sequences](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest-mark-django-db-request-database-access). Use it like so:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True, reset_sequences=True)
def mytest():
    [...]
```

Comment: Great find with py.test. It took me a while to figure out why my tests were failing when moving from sqlite to posgres, adding reset_sequences did the trick because in posgres the IDs were incrementing between test functions.

Comment: There's a built-in Django way to do this, see Pooya's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a fixtures file - put whatever data you want in there; then edit it in your test as needed.

Although, that is harder to maintain. In my opinion - there are far better options that may work much more like what you intend.

You're better off using something like [`factory_boy`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) and generating the models (and related foreign keys) at instantiation with dummy data you provide.

That way you know *exactly* what is being tested and it's completely independent of everything else. The nice part is that with `factory_boy` you will have a `factories.py` file you can keep up to date much easier than working with some fixture.

There are other options like [`Mixer`](https://github.com/klen/mixer) or [`model_mommy`](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy), although I only have experience with `factory_boy` and `mixer`.

With `factory_boy` it might look something like this:

```
   def test_model_test1(self):
       factory.ModelFactory(
       some_specific_attribute='some_specific_value'
       )
       model = Model.objects.all().first()
       # Test against your model
```